# Does this class violate SRP?

Tags: solid-principles

Have a class:

```
class Printer
{
    public void StartPrintAndWaitForCompletion()
    {
        Start();
        WaitForCompletion();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        // some logic for start printing
    }

    private void WaitForCompletion()
    {
        // some logic that waits for specific state of printer queue
    }
}
```

1. Does this class violate SRP?
2. Method StartPrintAndWaitForCompletion does more than one thing. Should I remove it and always call Start() and WaitForCompletion() separately?

Answer (score 0):

This class appears to be dealing with printing, that's a single responsibility and it's fine.

You definitely should do something with `StartPrintAndWaitForCompletion`, but you need to decide what to do, with the most obvious solution being to simply call it `print`.

Comment: Additionally think about [levels of abstraction](http://principles-wiki.net/principles:single_level_of_abstraction). The class `Printer` is one level of abstraction. What is it good for? Look at its public methods. Ah, it prints (after renaming). This is another level. What does it mean to "print"? Read the method and go down one level: It's starting the printer device and waiting for it to complete. What means "starting the printer"? Look at `Start` and descend yet another level of abstraction and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are probably not violating SRP at the class level since it's reasonable that the `Printer` class deals with printing. However, you seem to have a leaky abstraction. `StartPrintAndWaitForCompletion` tells too much about the actual implementation.

If your API is synchronous then calling something like `Printer.print` already has to wait until the printing is done to return the control to the calling method. If you want to design an asynchronous API then I'd opt for a Future-like API. In C# you can use [tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I think it does not break SRP.  But you can change the public method name. Because it tells about actual implementation, thus break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Single responsibility principle says:
"A class should have only one reason to change"
(see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Printing logic is one responsibility evidently belonging to Printer.
It may change separately.

Waiting for completion is another responsibility which also may change separately (whether waiting is always needed? how much time to wait? what to do if waiting timeout reached, etc.) I would suggest moving this logic to another class (look at task execution frameworks available for your language).